# Java MOOC 92.3 ( I want to understand how to solve this question, not just be provided an answer)

Tags: java, date

This exercise is from Java MOOC 92.3

Simply, I have two dates.
And a method which gives me the difference of the two.

(for instance: 3/10/2011 and 3/9/2012)

My method states that as long as the **month** and the **day** are greater than the later, then simply subtract the one for which the method is called.

Here's the problem:

If a date given as a parameter has a greater year, then when I subtract the two I come out with a negative number (ex: 2011 - 2012).

```
 public int differenceInYears(MyDate comparedDate){
    int result = 0;

    if(this.month >= comparedDate.month && this.day >= comparedDate.day){

        result = this.year - comparedDate.year;

    }else{
        result = this.year - comparedDate.year;
        result--;
    }

    return result;
```

The code beyond the else is for the case in which the year is not what it may look to be (Example: If I was born in May 2000 and I technically should be 20 since it is 2020, but since it is not May yet, I am therefore 19).

My conditions are still met within the first if statement, even though the result is not correct. I have tried finding a case where I can appease both cases where it does not matter what date goes first, but I am struggling with the logic. Would appreciate input.

Answer (score 1):

First, if I understand correctly that this is an exercise, it’s a fine exercise. For production work one would never invent their own date class but would and should use `LocalDate` from the standard library for a date. And `ChronoUnit.YEARS.between()` for finding your age.

If you have not yet had your birthday this year, you want to subtract one year from the result. This is correct. So how do we determine whether this year’s birthday is in the future? Take a look at the following possibilities. I have not run your code, so have filled out the last column from what I think will happen from reading the code.

```
Today  Birthday  Subtract 1?  Does your code subtract 1?
--------------------------------------------------------
Apr 3  Feb 1     No           No
Apr 3  Feb 6     No           Yes
Apr 3  Apr 1     No           No
Apr 3  Apr 6     Yes          Yes
Apr 3  May 1     Yes          Yes
Apr 3  May 6     Yes          Yes
```

Another way to put the question: if the months are different, do we need to compare the day of month too?

I like your attitude. In accordance with your title I am not giving away the correctly working code. I too am convinced that you will not only learn more from writing it yourself, it will also give you greater pleasure. If you’re still stuck, please leave a comment and I’ll take one more look.

**EDIT:** For the problem of getting a negative result if the dates are in the opposite order: The simplest solution is to check the result after you’ve calculated. If it is negative, redo the entire calculation with the dates reversed. That is, with `this.` and `comparedDate.` in each other’s places. One elegent option is that in this case you tell the other `MyDate` object to do the calculation instead. Call the `differenceInYears` method of the other object passing `this` as argument.

Comment: I will report back with what I go with, or if I get stuck again. Thank you.